# How do I get MutationResult from higher order component created by graphql()

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

React Apollo Mutations allow me to create a component that takes in a MutationResult with `{ data, loading, error }` as a prop: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#mutation-render-prop

Now if I was to use the higher order component created by `graphql()`

```
function MyComponent({ mutate }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      mutate({
        variables: { foo: 42 },
      });
    }}>
      Mutate
    </button>
  );
}

export default graphql(gql`mutation { ... }`)(MyComponent);
```

My component will only have `mutate` as a prop. How do I get `{ data, loading, error }` into the component?

Comment: You can read it in the docs actually. It says that the `mutate` returns a Promise. So you can use `.then` to get the result from the mutation or `.catch` in case there was an error. In the case of the loading, you can do it with component state, calling `setState({ loading: true})` before the `mutate` and `setState({ loading: false})` after it. Hope it helps!

Comment: @qmateub This is good information. You should write it as an answer. I will mark yours as the answer once I have verified it.

Answer (score 0):

The Mutation is a promise, so you can receive the values inside of a then, and return them as needed.
If you have async and await you can return the data and use await so you can have access to it in a synchronous style of code.

```
function MyComponent({ mutate, setState }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => 
      mutate({
        variables: { foo: 42 },
      }).then(data => {
        // Process your data as needed here:
        setState({ data });
      }).catch(err => console.error('Our Error: ', err);
    }>
      Mutate
    </button>
  );
}

export default graphql(gql`mutation { ... }`)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

@allenylzhou

You can read it in the docs actually. It says that the mutate returns a Promise. So you can use `.then` to get the result from the mutation or `.catch` in case there was an error. In the case of the loading, you can do it with component state, calling `setState({ loading: true})` before the mutate and `setState({ loading: false})` after it. Hope it helps!